# React-Native - Calling Parent Method from Child Method

Tags: react-native

I have a Child, Parent Component and i need the Parent Component method to be called from a Child Component method.

### CODE

```
class Social extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);

                var tabLabel = this.props.tabLabel;

                this.state = { text: 'Search ' + tabLabel + ' here...' , textInput: ''};
              }
                doneClick() {
                    this.props.showTrans;
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                      if (request.readyState !== 4) {
                        return;
                      }

                      if (request.status === 200) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                      } else {
                        console.warn('error');
                      }
                    };

                    request.open('GET', "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=tupac&key=AIzaSyDFOz50C_XkuEh2T-2XTN9fqm_5xHYzbg8");
                    request.send();
                }
                      render() {

                        return (
                            <View style={styles.menu} >


                                    <View style={styles.searchbar} >
                                    <Image style={{marginTop: 10 ,marginLeft: 10 , width: 20, height: 20}} source={require('./images/search.png')} />
                                    <TextInput
                                            onSubmitEditing={ this.doneClick }
                                         style={{marginLeft: 5, color: '#757575', width: width - 80, height: 40, fontSize: 11,}}
                                         onChangeText={(textInput) => this.setState({textInput})}
                                         placeholder={this.state.text}
                                          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                         />
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.sep} >
                                </View>

                            </View>

                        );
                      }
                    }
```

This is Social Child Component

### CODE

```
class ScrollableTabBarView extends Component {

                    constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                        this.showTrans = this.showTrans.bind(this);
                        this.state = { transWidth: 0,transHeight: 0,tabScroll: null };
                        alert('dddd');

                    }



                    hideTrans() {
                        this.setState({ transHeight: 0, transWidth: 0 });
                    }
                    showTrans() {
                        this.setState({ transHeight: width, transWidth: height });
                    }

                  render() {
                    return (<View style={{ width: width, height: height, position: 'absolute' }}>
                    <ScrollableTabView
                      style={{marginTop: 40, }}
                      initialPage={0}
                      renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar/ >}
                    >
                      <Text tabLabel='User'>My</Text>
                      <Social  tabLabel='Settings'/>
                      <Social showTrans={ this.showTrans } hideTrans={ this.hideTrans }  tabLabel='Youtube'></Social>
                      <Social tabLabel='Vimeo'>favorite</Social>
                      <Social tabLabel='MySpace'>project</Social>
                    </ScrollableTabView>

                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', top: 0, left: 0,width: this.state.transWidth, height: this.state.transHeight, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor:'rgba(52,52,52,0.5)' }}>
                    <Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={require('./images/loader.gif')}/>

                    </View>

                    </View>)

                  }
                }
```

Parent Component.

How do i get this.props.showTrans to get called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost calling it. It should be

```
doneClick = () => {
  this.props.showTrans();
  ....
}
```

You might still get an error since showTrans will be called in the scope of your child component. You might want to make your showTrans, hideTrans as ES2015 class properties shown below or manually bind it so that "this" scope is proper.

```
hideTrans = () => {
  this.setState({ transHeight: 0, transWidth: 0 });
}
showTrans = () => {
  this.setState({ transHeight: width, transWidth: height });
}
```

Comment: i get an error saying undefined is not an object evaluating this.props.showTrans

Comment: Ah. You need to change done click to class property as well. Updated the answer.